# DiO-Membrane Exosome Labeling Kits

Tags: biological-neural-network

[DiO-Membrane Exosome Labeling Kits](https://www.creative-biolabs.com/exosome/category-exosome-labeling-282.htm)
Exosomes are membrane-derived particles surrounded by phospholipids released by cells. Labeling exosome with fluorescent dyes is an effective method for exosome visualization, which is beneficial to the research and application of exosomes.
Creative Biolabs provides several Membrane EVs Labeling & Purification Kits for labeling exosomes, which can be used in most applications that require visualization of labeled exosomes for tracking studies. These products have the following advantages:
Specific: these products are exclusively designed for exosome labeling which delivers a robust signal specific for exosome and very low levels of background signal.
Compatible: these products are suitable for delivering robust performance on exosomes isolated using all methods tested, including ultracentrifugation, and column-based workflows.
Easy-to-use: Protocols are quick and simple.
Sensitive: As little as 50 µg of exosomes.

DiO-Membrane Exosome Labeling Kits.